# What does it mean to conform to a protocol consisting of only @property

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to understand someone's code and ran into this.

There is a header file in which there is a protocol that specify a property of a UIButton.

In a separate implementation file (not the implementation for this header file), it was checking if a view controller "conformsToProtocol"

I understand if you have to conform to a protocol of methods, you have to implement those methods. But here,

What constitute conform and non-conform here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that whatever conforms to that protocol must have the specified properties. (Remember, @properties are basically just shorthand for the underlying setter and getter methods, so you can also conform by having the appropriate setters and getters.)

Comment: Thank you for the explaination